# ajax in admin menu

Tags: ajax

Following the tutorial listed [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins), I'm the data isn't being saved to the user meta I'm trying to set.  The process itself seems simple enough, but the meta data isn't being saved.  I don't get any console errors and the little success animation I have runs when I run the jQuery script.

```
<?php
    add_action( 'admin_footer', 'ring_jquery' );

    function ring_jquery() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('.ring-submit').on('click', function(){
        var u = jQuery(this).attr('user'),
            c = jQuery('.agt_ringc[user="'+u+'"]').val(),
            x = jQuery('.agt_ringx[user="'+u+'"]').val(),
            formData = 'ringu='+u+'&ringc='+c+'&ringx='+x;
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            success: function(e){

                jQuery('.success[user="'+u+'"]').fadeIn(400).delay(400).fadeOut(400);

            },
            error: function(){

                jQuery('.fail[user="'+u+'"]').fadeIn(400).delay(400).fadeOut(400);

            }
        });
    });

</script>
<?php
} //End ring_jquery()

add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'ring_callback');

function ring_callback() {
    global $wpdb; // this is how you get access to the database

    $ringu = $_POST['ringu'];
    $ringc = $_POST['ringc'];
    $ringx = $_POST['ringx'];

    update_user_meta($ringu,'agt_ringc',$ringc);
    update_user_meta($ringu,'agt_ringx',$ringx);

    die(); // this is required to return a proper result
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_action('wp_ajax_ring_callback', 'ring_callback');
```

Should be the hook you must be using to enable ring_callback function call.

Comment: Indeed!  I figured this out a little later.  I was also missing the `action=ring_callback` var setting in my data string.

Comment: I am glad you did :) But this is a common mistake i guess and this answer should be helpful to other community users.